# MERN Stack: User ID returns null on POST

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose-schema, mern

I'm working on an app that uses a MERN stack with passport JS for authentication.

The ERD of the app is as follows:

```
user
site (belongs to user)
page (belongs to site)
```

I am able to register, login, and get a user id & token returned:

```
* {_id: "5db9760b7ba2c21e9a2659f3", email: “test@gmail.com", token: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9"}
    * email: “test@gmail.com" token: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9" _id: "5db9760b7ba2c21e9a2659f3" __proto__: Object
```

The token is saved in local storage.

Now, I am trying to get the next step in the ERD working by creating a site. However, when I try to make a `POST` request for the site, I get the user ID is returning undefined:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api/users/undefined/sites/ 404 (Not Found)
```

In terminal, I get this error:

`(node:24299) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "current" at path "_id" for model "Users"`

#### Express

```
//Create Site
router.post('/:user_id/sites/:site_id/pages', function (req, res, next) {
  const saveData = {
    userId: req.params.user_id,
    siteId: req.params.site_id,
    content: req.body.page.content
  };
  const condition = {
    userId: req.params.user_id,
    siteId: req.params.site_id
  };

  console.log(saveData);

  Content.exists(condition)
    .then((data) => {
      if (data == false) {
        Content.create(saveData)
          .then((data) => {
            res.send(data);
          });
      }
    })

})
```

#### REACT (api-helper.js)

```
// LOGIN USER
export const loginUser = async (loginData) => {
  const resp = await api.post('/login', { user: loginData });
  const token = resp.data.user.token;
  storeToken(token);
  return (resp)
}

//POST - CREATE SITE
export const newUserSite = async (user_id, data) => {
  getToken();
  const resp = await api.post(`${user_id}/sites`, { site: data });
  return (resp.data);
}
```

#### REACT (App.js)

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    const user = await loginUser();
    this.getUserSites();
    const allUserSites = await getUserSites();
    this.setState({
      users: user,
    });
    console.log(allUserSites);
  };


//Create Site
  newSite = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const userID = this.state.users.id;
    const site = await newUserSite(userID, this.state.formData);
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      sites: [...prevState.sites, site],
      currentSiteId: site.id,
    }))
    this.props.history.push("/edit")
  }
```

Since there is a token that is returned and saved to local storage, I'm unable to understand why the user id is returning as undefined.

Comment: Your loginUser method expects a parameter (loginData), but you are calling it like this   const user = await loginUser();

Comment: Also I think api.post(`${user_id}  => must be api.post(`/${user_id}